# ejabberd on vm not connect to another xmmp server (iptables dnat dport 5269)

Tags: iptables, virtual-machines, ejabberd, dnat

i migrate a ejabberd server to a vm with only private ip. is work fine but not connect to anothers xmmp servers.

log:
s2s connection: xxxx -> gmail.com (remote server not found)

telnet test:
telnet xmpp-server.l.google.com 5269
Connection time out

in the host add iptables nat port 5269 to internal ip.
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5269 -j DNAT --to-destination x.x.x.x:5269

the host have a masquerade for all out to eth with public ipv4.

if i remove this nat the telnet test is ok, but i cant connect to port 5269 on internal ip.

Any ideas?

Thank...

Comment: JAaaa just fixed!! :D

the problem if with nat rule... only add interface with public ip for nat:

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ETHERNET_WITH_PUBLIC_IP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5269 -j DNAT --to-destination x.x.x.x:5269

Sorry i dont have perm for public answer to my own questions :P

"Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:

    Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead."